# `dotenv-webpack` env vars undefined

Tags: webpack, dotenv

Trying to get some environment variables to expand in some code. 
Using the [dotenv-webpack](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack) and a local `.env` file to make this work. But the env var is always undefined.

```
 ....
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './.env'),
      systemvars: true,
      silent: false,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        PATH_PREFIX: JSON.stringify(process.env.PATH_PREFIX),
      },
    }),
 ....
```

In my `.env` file I have the following..

`PATH_PREFIX=/test/contents`

And finally in my code, I have this..

`console.log('process.env', process.env.PATH_PREFIX);`

I'm running this with..

`./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --config ./webpack.config.js --display-error-details`

And when it is run, `PATH_PREFIX` is undefined.